# Dynamically added partial view to existing DIV on button click in JQUERY and MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am adding a partial view to my existing div to add more repeated user fields. This is how i am doing:

```
     <div class="userDiv"> Existing HTML goes here </div>
```

AND anchor link  to add another user

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Add another User", "AddUser", null, new { id = "addAnotherUserLink" })  


$("#addAnotherUserLink").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.href,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html) { $(".userDiv").append(" <div class='userPartialDiv'><a href='#' class='deleteRow'>Delete</a>" + html + "</div>"); }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

AND when you click on delete it is removing the appended partial view.

```
    $(document).on("click", ".deleteRow", function () {
                   $(this).closest(".userPartialDiv").remove();
                   return false;
               });
```

My question is how can i give a number to it.
Let's say I have added or clicked four times on add another user button, it is going to add four partial views to existing DIV. But I need to give them a number like user1, user2, user3, user4. But when i delete one of them lets say 2nd one, then it shoud automatically re order then to user1, user2 ,user3 for rest of them instead of user1, user3, user4.

And please also help me how to add this data into the data base. I mean how to read the data from partial views into controller by looping through number of partial views added.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to posting when "deleting", use a data model and replay the remaining partial views on delete appending the for loop counter on the remaining user entries.

Comment: No i have to do it dynamically on front end using jquery.